# Android ViewPager2 - how to detect user initiated page change

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager2

I have the ViewPager2 callback setup but need to detect when a user initiated page change has completed. The callback won't differentiate between user initiated and code initiated. Here's what I have now:

```
ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback swipeListener = new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //I want to run code only if user initiated this page change
            //but this runs whether user initiated or code initiated
        }
}
```

The page change that is done via code:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(targetSlide);
```

The [docs for ViewPager2](https://androidx.de/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.html) show a `isUserInputEnabled()` method which tells you if a user "can" change the page manually, but I need to detect if the user "did" initiate the page change.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [isFakeDragging](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#isFakeDragging()) inside [registerOnPageChangeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#registerOnPageChangeCallback(androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback)) to detect whether the drag is fake or initiated by user.

> Returns true if a fake drag is in progress.

```
...onPageScrolledonPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
    if(isFakeDragging)
        {// fake scroll}
    else{// user scroll}
}
```

Comment: I don't initiate a fake drag in code to change the page, so `isFakeDragging` will always return `false` here.

Comment: then what do you mean by `code initiated`? you need to add the complete details about your use case. Anyhow, if possible, use fake drag for best practices and desired behavior.

Comment: OP edited.  I am using `viewPager.setCurrentItem()`.

Comment: @lilbiscuit then the easy solution is to use a boolean flag to track the change or the other option is to use a touch event listener to detect the user touch and proceed accordingly.

Comment: How do you use the position to get the view that the viewPager2 is looking at?

Answer (score 0):

One can override viewpager2 to detect a page change like so:

```
    viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        }
    });
```